# TextEditor search and replace regex remove spaces from a phone number

Tags: regex, textmate, text-editor, replace

So regular expressions are a bit of a failing in my skill set. I can create some very basic search expressions, but come time to do search and replace, I fail.

My text editor is TextMate if that helps, but this should be fairly general to text editors in general.

I've got a CSV file open in TextMate. I need to remove all white space from all the phone numbers. The phone numbers are in the format: DD DDD DDDD or DDDD DD DDDD, or some other variations.

The regex to find these numbers should be fairly simple, but how on earth do I use the output of that to do the replacing?

I'm after a search regex, and the replace regex, in the context of search/replace in a text editor.

Search: ,[\d+\s*]+, (at least one digit, 0 or more spaces, repeating and greedy)
Replace: ?

Comment: Got an example of what it exactly looks like now and what you'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses to make a group, and $1, $2, etc in the replace field to match the group number like so:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Though for my case, the following works slightly better: `([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)`